# Updating custom file path when uploading file in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django admin interface to upload a file on server. I'm using a dynamic path to save it that depends on the other fields on the webpage. 
The file should save to:

```
 *"mixes/%session_number/%day_of_play/%file_name".* 

(where %session_number, %day_of_play, and %file_name are other fields on the upload page)
```

So I've manage to find out how to delete the file from the server when the file is deleted from the admin page by making a custom delete() method, and how to delete and upload a new file to the right path if the file is modified from the admin page with a custom save() method. However, I'd also like the file to be moved when I edit any of the 3 variables included in the path name since that'd make more sense. So if I edit a field (say session_number) on the admin interface for a given file, I'd like it to be moved from `"mixes/1/%day_of_play/%file_name" to "mixes/2/%day_of_play/%file_name"`. But I can't seem to make something that simple work. Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import os
import datetime

class Session(models.Model):
    sessionName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startTime = models.TimeField('Session Starting Time')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sessionName

def get_saving_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('mixes', '%s' % instance.session, '%d' % instance.airDate.year, '%d' % instance.airDate.month, '%d' % instance.airDate.day, filename)


class Mix(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    airDate = models.DateField('Airing date')
    mix = models.FileField(upload_to=get_saving_path)  #'mixes/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        storage, path = self.mix.storage, self.mix.path
        super(Mix, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        storage.delete(path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            original = Mix.objects.get(id=self.id) 
            if original.session != self.session:
                original.mix.delete(save=False)
            if original.mix != self.mix:
                original.mix.delete(save=False)
        except: pass
        super(Mix, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So what I'm doing in the last method is checking if we're editing the object or creating a new one, and if we are editing, I check the database field for what's in it. If the mix is different I delete the old file and upload the new one. But I'd like the same to be done if the object session is changed. It's not working though, and I can't figure out why. (I found this method on another stackoverflow post, so it's possible I haven't quite understood it which is why it's not working right now...)

Here's what my database says:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata radio.Mix
[{"pk": 1, "model": "radio.mix", "fields": {"mix": "mixes/Evening/2014/7/21/Since I've Been Loving You.mp3", "session": 2, "name": "LedZep", "airDate": "2014-07-23"}}]
$ python manage.py dumpdata radio.Mix
[{"pk": 1, "model": "radio.mix", "fields": {"mix": "mixes/Morning/2014/7/1/Gallows Pole.mp3.mp3", "session": 1, "name": "LedZep", "airDate": "2014-07-01"}}]
$ python manage.py dumpdata radio.Mix
[{"pk": 1, "model": "radio.mix", "fields": {"mix": "mixes/Morning/2014/7/1/Gallows Pole.mp3.mp3", "session": 2, "name": "LedZep", "airDate": "2014-07-01"}}]
```

So I upload my first file with all the fields filled in, seems to work fine.
Then I change the uploaded file when editing my object and the file path updates. I've also changed the session from Evening (2) to Morning (1), that updates too (and the old file is deleted).
Finally, I edit once more my object but this time only changing the session from morning (1) to evening (2). My session field updates, but my file path doesn't and I can't figure out why.

I'm using `Django 1.6`